# Configurations of JMS Queue for saving low priority informations on sql server

Tags: glassfish, jms, glassfish-3, message-queue

i would like to setup a JMS Queue on a Glassfish v3 Server for saving some protocoll informations on a sql server.

My first try ended up in lot's of deadlocks on the sql server.

My first question is: Are the messages in a queue processes after each other or in parallel. How do it set it up to process the messages after each other. Time does not play a role. I want to bring only a minimum load to the sql server.

The second: Where can i see how much messages are waiting in the queue for processing?
I had a look into the monitoring of glassfish and also the

`http://server:adminport/__asadmin/get?monitor=true&pattern=server.applications.ear.test.war.TestMessageDrivenBean.*`

But i could not see a "tobeprocessed" value or s.t. like that.

Many thanks,

Hasan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener you bind to the queue will process messages as they arrive.  It responds to an onMessage event.  You don't have to set up anything.

You do have to worry about what happens if the queue backs up because the listener(s) can't keep up.

You should also configure an error queue where messages that can't be processed go.

Have you thought about making the queue and database operation transactional?  That way the message is put back on the queue if the database INSERT fails.  You'll need an XA JDBC driver and a transaction manager to do it.

Comment: So the jms.Queue is not a "FirstInLastOut Array" and a message driven bean is sitting at the end a processing the messages? It's a async method call?

Comment: No, queues are FIFO.  Yes, queues and topics are asynch from the point of view of the client: add the message to the queue and go away; don't worry about what's done or how long it takes.

Comment: Queue is a bit irritating. I think about s.t. like a queue on the highway and nothing parallel. 
And "Maximum Pool Size" controls how much mdb's can be started at the same time? This way the "Maximum Pool Size" make's sense.

Comment: I don't see why you're irritated.  They're very much about parallelism.  What do you think all those MDB's are acting like when more than one message comes in?  The word "queue" is deliberate.  Think about a line at a bank.  When the line gets long, add more tellers and the line gets shorter.  When times are slow, just have one.  The principle is exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe it's because i grow up with bank's that allways had one queue for each teller. :-) But thank you very much. I understood what you mean.